What types of successful transactions would incur zero Computer Unit?
I'm exploring the raw dataset and realize that quite a lot of transactions consume zero computer units. Just curious to know what types of successful transactions would incur zero Computer Unit? Are these transactions generally implementing transfer with the system program?

Do you have any examples of transactions that consume 0 compute units? It's hard to debug without more info!
